# Get category 'thumbnail' image and text within product pages

Tags: category, magento-1

We'd like to use the category thumbnail and text as brand info to show the logo and description on the product page. How can I get these information on the product page?

I'm working in:
.../template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach didn't work for me because:

A product can be in several categories, so when you route to the product directly, it doesn't know the category. It's easy if you don't put products in more categories but more complex if you do.

I solved the problem with this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735324/get-a-products-parent-category-even-if-it-is-accessed-directly

Here is my code to get the thumbnail image and description text even if a product is in more than one category (hope this helps others):

```
        <?php
            //load all categories where the product exists
            $cat = $_product->getCategoryCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            foreach($cat as $category){
                //check if the categorie in the array has a thumbnail and desc. text
                if($category->getThumbnail() && $category->getDescription()){
                    echo '<div class="cd-brand-logo"><img src="' . Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/' . $category->getThumbnail() .'" alt="' . $category->getName() . ' logo"></div>';
                    echo '<p>' . $category->getDescription() . '</p>';
                    // exit the loop if success
                    break; 
                }
                else{
                    echo '<p>Thumbnail or description is missing here.</p>';
                }
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this might be help you

```
    If(Mage::registry('current_catgory')){
    $Cat=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(Mage::registry('current_catgory'));
    $name=$Cat->getName();
$thum=  Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$Cat->getData('thumbnail');
    }
```

This **code is work if  you coming to product page from category page**

**Let me know ,if you have any issue**

Comment: Hey.is its works?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

**Show All category with thumbnail on homepage**

[image: Show All category with thumbnail on homepage]

Comment: Posting the code as text, using the available code formatting tools, will be more valuable to future searchers than posting an image. The image isn't searchable, copy and pasteable, etc.